# how we create line between two cordinates on polymap?

Tags: geocoding, geojson, polymaps, svg, d3

I am working on d3 and polymaps, I plot map and create circle on the given latitude and longitude which retrieves from the JSON file but now I want to connect those circles with line. I tried to do it with SVG but I am unable to find the accurate result.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I did write this code but only the points are been plotted

```
{
  // JavaScript Document

 var po = org.polymaps;
 var svg = n$("#map").add("svg:svg");

 var map = po.map()
.container($n(svg))
.center({lat: 33.787, lon: -118.195})
.zoom(9)
.add(po.interact());

map.add(po.image()
.url(po.url("http://{S}tile.cloudmade.com"
+ "/1a1b06b230af4efdbb989ea99e9841af" // http://cloudmade.com/register
+ "/998/256/{Z}/{X}/{Y}.png")
.hosts(["a.", "b.", "c.", ""])));

 map.add(po.compass()
.pan("none"));



//this is for creating dots on the map(see in black color) work well
 map.add(po.geoJson()
.features([{geometry: {coordinates: [[-118.195, 33.768],[-117.914, 33.768]], type: "MultiPoint"}}])
 );

//this is for creating line on the map but not working
 map.add(po.geoJson()
.features([{geometry: {coordinates: [[-118.195, 33.768],[-117.914, 33.768]], type:  "LineString"},properties: {"stroke": "red","stroke-width": .2,"fill-opacity":.6}}]));







}
```

Comment: I found it, the best way to do this to have D3+polymaps together. As there are few limitation to polymaps.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var map = po.map();
var layer = po.geoJson();
var featAtoB = {type: "Feature", geometry: {type: "LineString", 
               coordinates: [[14,50], [6,49]]},
               properties: {prop0: "value0",prop1: 0.0}};
layer.features([featAtoB]);

map.add(layer);
```

i hope it helps you...